# Синтаксис С++ (pair)

Tags: c++

Маленький вопрос: как можно объявить двумерный pair-массив n на n?

Comment: `pair matrix[n][n]`? `std::pair<char,int> matrix[n][n];`?

Comment: Что такое "pair-массив"?

Answer (score 1):

```
pair<char,int> m[n][n];
```

или

```
vector<vector<pair<char,int>>> m;
```

тут надо не забыть `resize` векторов.

задание элемента:

```
m[0][0]=make_pair((char)(' '),(int)(334));
```

Comment: Зачем лишние приведения типов? Можно просто `make_pair<char, int>(' ', 334)`, или даже `make_pair(' ', 334)`, правда в последнем случае придется за типами аргументов следить.

Comment: Что значит лишнее? Привидение типов будет по любому и в том и в другом случае либо явно (как в моём варианте) или неявно. А последний вариант выдаёт вместо адекватного ответа: не те аргументы строку в 1000 символов ещё и не в том месте.

Comment: литерал `' '` и так типа `char`, литерал `334` и так типа `int`. Зачем лишний раз приводить тип? Почему тогда получившуюся пару явно не приводите к `pair<char, int>`?

Comment: Значит это преобразование фиктивное и в ассемблере его не будет. А куда писать char и int неважно. А зачем приводить пару к такой если она и так такая? 1 указания компилятору хватит.

Comment: А зачем приводить int к int'у, если он и так такой?